# Exporting to text using access query with parameters

Tags: ms-access, export

Greetings,

I have an access query which uses built in parameters (e.g. [start date]) to prompt a user to enter a date parameter when the query is ran.

In most cases this has worked fine except today I tried to export the query to a text file and I am receiving an error:

> Too few parameters. Expected 2.

This makes sense as there are two parameters in the query [start date] and [stop date], the reason it errors is that I am never prompted to supply a value.

If I export to Excel this works OK, just not to text files.

Any suggestions on how to get around this issue or allow me to export the query to a text file?

Thank you,

[Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836/brettski)

Example Access Query:

```
SELECT PR_EARN.Emp_No, PR_EARN.Pay_Code, PR_EARN.Hours, PR_EARN.Rate, PR_EARN.Pay_Amt, PR_EARN.Pay_Date
FROM PR_EARN
WHERE (((PR_EARN.Pay_Date) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple more methods:

- There is a workaround given in the Microsoft's [KB269671](https://web.archive.org/web/20120411034555/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/269671).
  Basically, you have to use an intermediary query with a special syntax.
- You can also change the query to a *Make Table* query and then export its data.
- Use and intermediary invisible datasheet form whose `RecordSource` is set to the query and then have it's `FormLoad` event export the form to text then close the form.
  Just opening the form would prompt the user to enter the parameters and then automatically save it.

[Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923274/exporting-to-text-using-access-query-with-parameters/923314#923314) may still be the simplest one though.

Comment: Nice catch! I missed that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new form called Export.  Put two textboxes on the form, and name them StartDate and EndDate.  Save the form.  Change your query to read the following:

```
SELECT PR_EARN.Emp_No, PR_EARN.Pay_Code, PR_EARN.Hours, PR_EARN.Rate, PR_EARN.Pay_Amt, PR_EARN.Pay_Date
FROM PR_EARN
WHERE (((PR_EARN.Pay_Date) Between Forms!Export!StartDate And Forms!Export!EndDate));
```

Open the form by double-clicking it.  Fill in the two date fields, and leave the form running.  Export your query in the usual way.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but what a pain in the ass.  Is this a bug with MS Access, where it doesn't prompt for parameters in the Export Text Wizard?

Comment: The prompt for parameters thing is really just a quirk of the Access UI. It knows how to deal with the missing parameters, the export text wizard doesn't. In a real Access application, some code would be written that would plug parameter values directly into the query.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by using the eval function. So instead of:

```
Between [Forms]![Reporting Import and Export]![date_exportstart] And [Forms]![Reporting Import and Export]![date_exportend]
```

Use `Eval`:

```
Between Eval("[Forms]![Reporting Import and Export]![date_exportstart]") And Eval("[Forms]![Reporting Import and Export]![date_exportend]")
```