# Output query to text: Too few parameters, expected 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

This is my sql code if anyone can help me look at it and why it is not responding and give the error message. Note that the relationships are: `table1` and `table2` are connected by `ResetFrequency`; `table1` and `table3` are connected by `AccountNumber`.

```
SELECT table1.EffectiveDate, table2.ResetFrequency, table3.Loan
FROM (table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ResetFrequency = table2.ResetFrequency)
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.AccountNumber = table3.AccountNumber
WHERE (table1.EffectiveDate) = [Enter Date: mm/dd/yyy];
```

Comment: are you running it through MS Access?

Comment: yes. I'm running a query from Access

Comment: @user3750556: What's the error?

Comment: I have just replicated the problem. Looks like you will have to specify the date inside the query, like this: `WHERE (table1.EffectiveDate) = #07/01/2014#;` before exporting its data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting to text using access query with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923274/exporting-to-text-using-access-query-with-parameters)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried it didn't work.  When I took of the field 'table3.Loan', it runs fine. That field has been causing a lot of problems since I worked on this query.  Do you think it could be a relationship problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use following format:

```
SELECT z.EffectiveDate, z.ResetFrequency, table3.Loan
FROM (SELECT Table1.EffectiveDate, table2.ResetFrequency, table1.AccountNumber 
      FROM table1 
      LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ResetFrequency = table2.ResetFrequency)z
INNER JOIN table3 ON z.AccountNumber = table3.AccountNumber
WHERE (z.EffectiveDate) = [Enter Date: mm/dd/yyy];
```

Comment: `z` is an alias name for sub query. you can use your alias name instead of `z`.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the parentheses or brackets

```
SELECT table1.EffectiveDate, table2.ResetFrequency, table3.Loan
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ResetFrequency = table2.ResetFrequency
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.AccountNumber = table3.AccountNumber
WHERE table1.EffectiveDate = mm/dd/yyy;
```